# Can a matrix with a free variable ever have finite many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

If I have either an $n \times m$ or $n \times n$ matrix with a free variable. Can I ever have finitely many solutions if $x$ and $y$ could be any value? Each row has been reduced as much as possible. It is augmented. This is from an exam I just took and I responded that there were no finite solutions since there was a free variable. Sorry my brain is a bit fried.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
a & b & c & d & e & f \\
0 & 0 & a & h & i & k \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & m & n \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & p \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x & y 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: It should be formatted correctly now. Thank you coffeemath!

Comment: The format looks ok now. But what solutions? Where is the equation?

Comment: to answer this requires knowing if the first letter-entry in each row is assumed nonzero. If so the matrix is not yet row reduced. Also need to know the missing last column if it is an augmented matrix of a system

Comment: It was row reduced but not in rref form

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This reads like a Do-My-Homework-For-Me question. This not only makes many of us salty but also goes against the MSE Guidelines. Please take a [tour] on what makes a good question on this site.

Comment: Your matrix is *not* in row reduced echelon form

Answer (score 0):

A small note on terminology, a matrix by itself does not have "free variables" or "solutions". Those are features of systems of equations. However, when solving a system of linear equations, say $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $x$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector, and $b$ is an $m$-dimensional column vector, we often will solve them by representing them as an *augmented matrix* $[A|b]$. So while this matrix does encode all of the info about the system of equations, and it is totally fine to be loose with language at times, it is important to keep the minutiae in mind.

To answer your question, assuming your vector space is over $\mathbb{R}$ then you are correct. Since there is a free variable, the system cannot have finitely many solutions. It either has no solutions, or an infinite number of solutions.